# Changing Horse Attributes

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I have been making a plugin for a "portable horse" recently and I am very close to being done, my horses spawn in and despawn as I want them. However, the only thing that I am having a considerable amount of trouble with is changing Horse attributes like speed, color, jump height and Variant.
Here is my Code:

```
package io.github.bxnie.events;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Donkey;
import org.bukkit.entity.Horse;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.vehicle.VehicleExitEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

public class HorseSpawn implements Listener {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        if(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK){
            Player p = e.getPlayer();
            ItemStack item = e.getItem();

            if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.GRAY + "Donkey")) {
                Donkey donkey = (Donkey) p.getWorld().spawn(p.getLocation(), Donkey.class);
                donkey.setAdult();
                donkey.setTamed(true);
                donkey.setOwner(p);
                donkey.getInventory().setSaddle(new ItemStack(Material.SADDLE));
                donkey.setCustomName(ChatColor.GRAY + "Donkey");
                donkey.setPassenger(p);
            }

            if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.RED + "Brown Horse")) {
                Horse horsebrown = (Horse) p.getWorld().spawn(p.getLocation(), Horse.class);
                horsebrown.setAdult();
                horsebrown.setTamed(true);
                horsebrown.setOwner(p);
                horsebrown.getInventory().setSaddle(new ItemStack(Material.SADDLE));
                horsebrown.setCustomName(ChatColor.RED + "Horse");
                horsebrown.setPassenger(p);
            }

            if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "Black Horse")) {
                Horse horseblack = (Horse) p.getWorld().spawn(p.getLocation(), Horse.class);
                horseblack.setAdult();
                horseblack.setTamed(true);
                horseblack.setOwner(p);
                horseblack.getInventory().setSaddle(new ItemStack(Material.SADDLE));
                horseblack.setCustomName(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "Horse");
                horseblack.setPassenger(p);
            }

            if(item.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.WHITE + "White Horse")) {
                Horse horsewhite = (Horse) p.getWorld().spawn(p.getLocation(), Horse.class);
                horsewhite.setAdult();
                horsewhite.setTamed(true);
                horsewhite.setOwner(p);
                horsewhite.getInventory().setSaddle(new ItemStack(Material.SADDLE));
                horsewhite.setCustomName(ChatColor.WHITE + "Horse");
                horsewhite.setPassenger(p);
            }
        }
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void onPLayerDismount(VehicleExitEvent e) {
        if(e.getExited() instanceof Player) {
            if(e.getVehicle() instanceof Donkey) {
                Donkey donkey = (Donkey) e.getVehicle();
                if(donkey.getCustomName() != null) {
                    if(donkey.getCustomName().equals(ChatColor.GRAY + "Donkey")) {
                        donkey.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
            if(e.getVehicle() instanceof Horse) {
                Horse horse = (Horse) e.getVehicle();
                if(horse.getCustomName() != null) {
                    if(horse.getCustomName().equals(ChatColor.RED + "Horse")) {
                        horse.remove();
                    }
                    if(horse.getCustomName().equals(ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "Horse")) {
                        horse.remove();
                    }
                    if(horse.getCustomName().equals(ChatColor.WHITE + "Horse")) {
                        horse.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've done a ton of research but nothing really seems to help my case, is there any way that any of you know of to spawn in a horse with the custom attributes I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

When you believe you've researched enough, research a little more, I searched for `"bukkit change horse speed"` and [one of the top answers works perfectly](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/horse-speed.259180/). With that being said, let's try to solve your issue.

Everything you need is right in the [horse](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Horse.html) API, more specifically [#setColor()](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Horse.html#setColor-org.bukkit.entity.Horse.Color-), [#setStyle()](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Horse.html#setStyle-org.bukkit.entity.Horse.Style-), [#setJumpStrength](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/AbstractHorse.html#setJumpStrength-double-) and [#setVariant()](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/AbstractHorse.html#setVariant-org.bukkit.entity.Horse.Variant-). Changing variant may not work using that method due to deprecation, instead you need to create a different entity, such as a [skeletonHorse](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/entity/SkeletonHorse.html)

These methods are really straightforward:

```
Horse horseblack = (Horse) p.getWorld().spawn(p.getLocation(), Horse.class);
horseblack.setJumpStrength(2.0);
horseblack.setColor(Color.BLACK);

SkeletonHorse skeletonHorse = (SkeletonHorse) p.getWorld().spawn(p.getLocation(), SkeletonHorse.class);
```

Changing speed is a little different, but the method works for any mobs.

```
entity.getAttribute(Attribute.GENERIC_MOVEMENT_SPEED).setBaseValue(yourValue);
```